# Transparent stroke overlap in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke, effects

I'm trying to do a semi-transparent stroke on a path. When 2 different paths overlap (right) the area where they cross is darker, as expected. But if it a single path there is no such area (left). Any way I can get the single path to show overlap like the two separate paths?

[image: transparent strokes]

Comment: Your question is a bit ambigious on if you want the 2 paths not to show overlap or the one path to show overlap

Comment: edited to make it clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cut the shape into 2, or expand it and merge the pieces. It a bit similar to the question about [art brush overlap](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/how-to-overlap-custom-art-brush-shapes/65639#65639).

1. cut the line
2. expand
3. use shape builder to isolate the overlap.

[image]

Or you can use multiple splitted segments as a brush they also overlap as described in the linked post.

IN the oppsote case just group them and enable

Comment: The third option from the right, that's the result from the 3 steps you outlined?

Comment: @spiral yes, thats right

Comment: If you have butt caps instead of round you may not have to bother with deleting the overlap (depending on the curve of the path) so it's as easy as just cutting the path

Comment: @Cai no but it will have a small rendering artifact at the join

Comment: @joojaa of course... you'll get that with shape builder too though, no?

Comment: @Cai possibly didnt test