# How does one get an over/under effect on letters in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, typography, illustrator-effects

[image: Overlapping effect on letters]

I am having trouble figuring out how to create this effect in illustrator in an efficient way. A professor had shown me once and I never could figure it out afterward. I remember a few things like ungrouping them and creating outlines, but from there I am lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlap a continuous line on itself?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92466/how-to-overlap-a-continuous-line-on-itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make sure all strokes are expanded to outlines, you can use the shape builder tool to overlap and underlap strokes.

For example:

[image]

Then when you have finished you can apply a white stroke to the completed work.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation of the way I work on this case.

It's is simple and effective as you can see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once outlined, it’s down to actually working with the vectors - trimming and shifting snd relayering - one quick trip to speed this up: black fill, white stroke will make the first steps easier.