stroke changes its length
I need the stroke to be exactly as it is after applying roundcap from butt cap.  How can i stop this incresment on both ends?
Thank you


Draw a circle as big as you stroke at the end of your line then delete the part that's inside the circle

:O Thank you so much. Now I understand. At firstMy lil brain cant process what ya said. Now it can. Thank you.

OK, so your asking if a hypothetical version of round but cap stroke exists to complement the system. It does unfortunately not exist. But you can make one.

Image 1: Hypothetical round but cap does not exist
The manual method is just to cut your, or shapebuild a path with a circle at the end of your path that has the same width as your stroke.
The alternate method is to make pattern brush with a round end this would mimic the stroke you want. All you do is make a square and two semicircles and make the pattern brush out of those.

Image 2: A pattern brush made out of a square and two semicircles
The downside of the pattern brush is that your design is now much more complicated in terms of geometry.
What one really would want to have is a effect that can adjust the length of a path. But illustrator Dev team doe snot seemingly want to improve the effect system.

While your at it read: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65639/18306

you are as cute as a kitten. thank you so much. I am overwhelmed. I am still a baby compared to your knowledge. Thank you.
